# Getting a NumberFormatException with thymeleaf on th:field but not on others th:*

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, numberformatexception, spring-thymeleaf

I'm rather new to Thymeleaf, so this maybe a newbie mistake. And I've been looking everywhere online for an answer and haven't found one. So sorry if this is really basic.

Basically I'm using Thymeleaf with SpringBoot 2.6.7 and I want to populate a object using a form. Something I've been able to do in the past, but this time for the first time the object I want to populate contains a list of other objects. And it's getting quite tricky.

My html looks like this :

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/character}" th:object="${input}" method="post">
    
        <div th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, input.attributes.size - 1)}">
            <div th:object="${input.attributes[i]}">
                <input type="range" min="1" th:max="*{maxValue}" th:field="*{value}">  <!-- this doesn't work -->
                <p th:text="*{name} + ' = ' + *{value}"></p> <!-- this works -->
            </div>
        </div>
    
</form>
```

The error I get is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "i"`. So I'm guessing there's an issue with the parsing of `attributes[i]` when processing th:field.

I've tried to change the loop to `<div th:each="attribute : ${input.attributes}">` (and the associated th:object) but that just made it worse, got the `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'attribute' available as request attribute` error message.

If it's any help, here is my controller :

```java
@GetMapping("character")
public String startingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("input", new FormInput());
    return "character";
}

@PostMapping("character")
public String processingForm(@ModelAttribute FormInput input, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
        throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        log.error("something went wrong");
    }

    // Other stuff
    return "character";
}
```

My input class

```java
@Getter
public class FormInput{
    protected List<Attribute> attributes;

    public FormInput(){
        attributes= new ArrayList<>();
        for (AttributeEnum ae : AttributeEnum.values()) {
            attributes.add(new Attribute(ae.getName(), ae));
        }
    }
}
```

And the Attribute class

```java
@Getter
public class Attribute {
    protected String name;
    protected AttributeEnum typeAttribute;
    protected Integer value = 1;
    protected Integer maxValue = 5;

    public Attribute(String n, AttributeEnum ta){
        name = n;
        typeAttribute = ta;
    }

    public boolean setValue(Integer v){
        if (v > maxValue ) return false;
        value = v;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Does someone know a fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. So I'm posting the answer is anyone has the same issue.

```html
<div th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, input.attributes.size - 1)}">
    <input type="range" min="0" th:max="${input.attributes[i].maxValue}" th:field="${input.attributes[__${i}__].value}">   <!-- this works -->
</div>
```

Just had to replace `attributes[i]` with `attributes[__${i}__]`.